# Trigger Airflow tasks on file upload

Tags: python, airflow, scheduled-tasks

I am thinking of a way to trigger Airflow tasks when user uploads ANY file to the DAG directory, which Airflow operator may help in this case?

I know about the FileSensor operator, but as far as I understand it expects for a specific file to be uploaded to the directory.

If Airflow doesn't have such operators, what should I try in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder for uploaded files (for example 'user_upload/'). After that, get the all files under this folder and the time of modification or creation of files by [os.path.getmtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) or [os.path.getctime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime). After that, you can compare these times with template variables like *data_interval_start* or *ts* and take the new files.
If there are no new files, you can skip the downstream tasks using *AirflowSkipException*.